# Extracting year from string and parsing into an int

Tags: c#, string, parsing

Example...

`"6/1/1986 24:00,ak,us,light,180,51.88,-176.6580556"`

I'm trying to extract only `"1986"` but I keep getting an error saying "Input string was not in the correct format."

```cs
string date = data[0];
string year1 = date.Substring(4);
int year = int.Parse(year1);
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `Substring()` method? What makes you think that the code you posted should do what you want? It looks like you probably just forgot to include the second parameter. I.e. try `Substring(4, 4)`, so that you get the four characters starting at index 4, instead of all the rest of the characters starting at index 4. That said, even with that fixed, the code won't generalize to dates with two-digit months and/or days. You should probably learn about regex.

Comment: you don't need to use ``substring``,  1:parse ``date`` to ``DateTime``, 2-: get string ``year`` by calling ``ToString("yyyy")`` and parse it to ``int``

Comment: @Sajid - `ToString("yyyy")` - What?? To solve the problem of parsing an `int` from a complex `string`, you want to parse a `DateTime` from the same `string`, turn the year into a `string` and parse that into an `int`? Forgetting for a second that `DateTime.Year` is already an `int`...

Answer (score 2):

If the position of the year in the string is always the same - 4-5-6-7 characters, then:

```
string date = "6/1/1986 24:00,ak,us,light,180,51.88,-176.6580556";
int year = int.Parse(date.Substring(4, 4));
```

[Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

If the line format (position of the year) may be different, for example: "06/01/1986 24:00, ak, us, light, 180.51.88, -176.6580556", then use regular expressions:

[Regex(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex__ctor_System_String_)

Comment: Please don't link to external sites without first putting the relevant content in your answer. All answers on SO should be sufficient if the links were deleted. Only link to provide supporting evidence to the content you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to split the string using `" "` instead of `","` to get the date part and parse the first item with "d/M/yyyy" format or "M/d/yyy" depending on what you want.

```cs
var data = "6/1/1986 24:00,ak,us,light,180,51.88,-176.6580556";
var dateString = data.Split(" ")[0];
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var year = date.Year;
```

Comment: "Use of a 24-hour clock can remove ambiguity. The "midnight" term can be avoided altogether if the end of day is noted as 24:00 and the beginning of day as 00:00. While both notations refer to the same moment in time, the choice of notation allows its association with the previous night or with the following morning. This approach follows the 24-hour time specification of ISO 8601." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight

Comment: Extending to parse the time when the time isn't needed in the final answer is just allowing bugs to enter the code. Had the OP shown an example of a normal time and then `24:00` showed up in his data then his code would have failed. Less is more.

Comment: Also, the OP hasn't declared if this date is the 6th of January or the 1st of June. It is very likely that the OP has data that could break this code if `d/M/yyyy` is incorrect.

Comment: @Enigmativity I was saying that 24:00 was not a valid time for the .Net DateTime.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the data clearly has `24:00`, so an answer that uses time needs to handle this case and not just wave it away. It wouldn't be hard to handle it, but it just goes to reinforce my point about bugs.

Comment: Your edit is a good step in the right direction, but why now should it mention time at all?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have edited my answer to take into account your comments.

Comment: Good answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know the date/time format of the data part of the string we can't use `d/M/yyyy` or `M/d/yyyy` to parse the text as a date.

Since dates could be `31/12/1986` or `3/24/1986`, again not knowing the format, then we can't rely on the year being in a fixed position.

The clear choice at this point is `Regex`. Try this:

```
var raw = "6/1/1986 24:00,ak,us,light,180,51.88,-176.6580556";
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/(\d{4})");
var match = regex.Match(raw);
int year = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

That gives the `1986` as in `int`.